# "withdraw the question" in less formal way

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I'm trying to find more common way to say that I would like to withdraw/cancel/recall off (?) my question I sent few days ago. Can you suggest something?

Thank you
Hubert

Comment: A bit more information please. Sent via email? What is the reason? Do you already have the answer? Has the passage of time caused the question to become irrelevant?

Comment: Yes, sent via email. The reason is I missed something in data I analyzed and day later I found it, so question (I haven't receive respond yet) isn't necessary

Comment: I would say something to the effect of "Please disregard my previous question as I have already found the answer".

Comment: "That question is inoperative."  (With a tip of the hat to Ron Ziegler.)

Answer (score 1):

Fuggetaboudit! LOL

that's a folksy way of saying it

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

*Never mind* my question.

Comment: Simply "Never mind!" in a nasal Rosanne Roseannadanna voice.